# What's the parentNode of a "<tr>" ？

Tags: javascript, dom

I tried this：

```
<table id ="table1">
<tr id ="aa"><td>aa</td></tr>
<tr id ="bb"><td>bb</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick = "test()" value = "button">
```

and the javascript：

```
function test(){
    var parent=document.getElementById("table1");
    var child=document.getElementById("aa");
    parent.removeChild(child);  //this isn't work 
    //child.parentNode.removeChild(child);  this is ok!
}
```

the error:

> Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a
>   context where it does not exist

Hence,I was doubt,table isn't the parent of tr?

Comment: The parent of <tr> is <tbody> not <table> it gets automatically added if the tags lack it

Comment: You could easily have used the debugger to discover this.

Comment: check `parent == child.parentNode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the parent element is a `<tbody>` (the start and end **tags** for which are optional).

See the [HTML 5 tree construction rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable):

> 8.2.5.4.9 The "in table" insertion mode
>
> …
>
> A start tag whose tag name is one of: "td", "th", "tr"
>
> Clear the stack back to a table context. (See below.)
>
> Insert an HTML element for a "tbody" start tag token with no attributes, then switch the insertion mode to "in table body".
>
> Reprocess the current token.

Answer (score 1):

`<table>`s have an implicit `<tbody>` in the DOM, whether you put one in the HTML or not:

```
console.log(child.parentNode.nodeName); // TBODY
console.log(child.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName); // TABLE
console.log(child.parentNode.parentNode == parent); // true
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2uAaC/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var child = document.getElementById("aa");
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

You should add a null check, like

```
if(child != null && child.parentNode != null)
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);  
else
    alert("NULL reference");
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent node of TR is TBODY. Browser automatically creates TBODY if it was not defined.